# Sorting doesn't work on 2nd page of pagination - PHP

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

I've implemented pagination into my website which works great. The problem occurred when I tried adding in a 'sort by price' section of code into my website.. It sorts fine on page 1 of the pagination, but when I click on page 2, it seems to reset all of the products

I've got the following code for the sorting by price :

```
$orderby='';


if ( !empty($_GET['Sort']) && $_GET['Sort'] == 'PriceAsc' ) 
  {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY Cost ASC";
  } 

if ( !empty($_GET['Sort']) && $_GET['Sort'] == 'PriceDesc' ) 
  {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY Cost DESC";
  }
```

Then further down the page I have my pagination set up code, and within the query part of the code I have added in the variable $orderby which looks like this:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM laptops $orderby $limit");
```

Then lastly I've got the fetch array while loop at the bottom to echo out the data using:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
```

Could anyone help me/suggest how I could fix my code so that the sorting stays once I press page 2, 3 etc.. of my pagination.

Thanks

Comment: I think the error could be come from how you'r passing the value

Comment: @EmilioGort Which value? The sort value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the get variable 'sort' still set on page 2?? i.e. does the link to page 2 (from page 1) include this variable.

for example page.php?page=2&sort=PriceDesc

Comment: Nope, on page 1 it only shows example.php?Sort=PriceAsc, it doesn't list the pagenumber until I press page 2, then from here it switches to  example.php?pn=2

Comment: How would I get both to remain on the link ?

Comment: you will need to define the 'sort' variable in the page 2 url. e.g.  example.php?pn=2&sort=PriceDesc. You will have to code this on the link to page 2 on page 1.

Comment: you can make the link on page 1 like the following:
<a href="example.php?pn=2&sort=<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['sort']); ?>">Page 2</a>

Comment: Ah okay, I'll have a look at that and see what I can do I guess, Thanks George :)

Comment: Yeah your right, I just tried adding the code "?Sort=PriceDesc&pn=2" to my link at the top, and it worked, So I guess I know how to solve it, I just need to try figure out how to code it properly, thanks a lot for that, Appreciate it

Comment: no probs! also you may want to look into the offset clause for you sql statement. see this link http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm. so you can start displaying you results at an offset on the second page.

Comment: Alrite thanks, I'll take a look at it once i've managed to solve this :)

Comment: Got it fixed now finally, took me long enough, over 4 hours.. Shows how much of a noob coder I am, anyways thanks for your help, I kind of developed your idea into getting it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

$_GET gets a value if you set it. if you want to see URLs like page.php?page=2 without any variable definition, you must use $_POST.
Please note that you must post variables to page.php with a html form:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="{$_POST['sort'] ? $_POST['sort'] : ''}" />
 <input type="submit" name="p" value="2" />
</form>
```